# xparse empty arguments

Tags: optional-arguments, xparse

I have defined a command using `xparse` as

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\mymacro{o o o}
```

and I want to call it with various numbers of arguments (up to 3)

```
\mymacro, \mymacro[test][two], \mymacro[][][test]
```

etc...

The issue is that `[]` doesn't seem to return a `\NoValue` but an empty token as the tests I use `\IfNoValueTF` never return false on it.

Is there a way to make an "empty" argument like `\mymacro[]` set `#1` to `\NoValue` when it is an empty string?

Essentially I need "empty" arguments to be set to `\NoValue` for my code to work.

I could always do

```
\mymacro[\NoValue][test][\NoValue]
```

but of course that defeats the purpose of making it simple.

In my code I use `\IfNoValueTF{#n}` a lot but for it to work on empty arguments I would need something like `\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF`.

Comment: Instead of three optional arguments you might want to consider using key-value pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a mixture of [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and `\ifx` conditionals you can test for empty arguments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\mymacro{o o o}{
  \def\@tempa{#1}Arg 1 is \ifx\@tempa\@empty\relax empty\else #1\fi. \par
  \def\@tempa{#2}Arg 2 is \ifx\@tempa\@empty\relax empty\else #2\fi. \par
  \def\@tempa{#3}Arg 3 is \ifx\@tempa\@empty\relax empty\else #3\fi.
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\verb|\mymacro|:\par\mymacro

\verb|\mymacro[test][two]|: \par\mymacro[test][two]

\verb|\mymacro[][][test]|: \par\mymacro[][][test]

\verb|\mymacro[][][]|: \par\mymacro[][][]

\verb|\mymacro[one][][three]|: \par\mymacro[one][][three]
\end{document}​
```

Comment: This worked. Wasn't fun changing the different syntaxes({} to \else\fi) it at least it works. I imagine one could wrap IfNoValue to include empty values easy enough though.

Comment: \makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}[3]
{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}{\def\@tempa{#1}\ifx\@tempa\@empty#2\else#3\fi}}
\makeatother

Comment: `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` is more economic.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a `\IfNoValueOrEmpty` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}{mmm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}
   {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\mymacro}{ooo}{%
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{\typeout{\#1 is empty}}{\typeout{\string#1 is `#1'}}%
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#2}{\typeout{\#2 is empty}}{\typeout{\string#2 is `#2'}}%
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#3}{\typeout{\#3 is empty}}{\typeout{\string#3 is `#3'}}%
}

\mymacro
\mymacro[a]
\mymacro[a][b]
\mymacro[a][b][c]
\mymacro[][b]
\mymacro[][][c]
\mymacro[][][]
```

However, a command with three optional arguments is difficult to manage, because one needs to remember which is which. A key-value syntax might be easier to employ.

Comment: Should this solution work with the current xparse version (2013/11/19)? I do get an empty document when trying to use this.

Comment: @Jörg This document is not supposed to produce output, but only messages on the terminal.

Comment: Silly me, I missed the typeout...

Answer (score 8):

Empty arguments and `NoValue` ones are not the same (and indeed using `\NoValue` directly is not supported as we will soon change the definition). Unlike LaTeX2e's `\newcommand`, `xparse` differentiates between an argument which is given but is empty and one which is not given. Thus if you want to be able to have input of the form

```
\foo[][][baz]
```

you don't want a `NoValue` test at all, but rather

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{ O{} O{} O{} }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
    ...
  }
```

testing for an empty value using the code-level test. (We do not have a design-level empty test at the present time.)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but I can't seem to get it to work using lualatex. I've tried including expl3 and things but it causes problems later on in some of my macros

Comment: @AbstractDissonance `expl3` should not interfere with any code which does not use it. Could you give more detail?

Comment: All I know is when I replaced If `IfNoValueTF` with `tl_if_empty:NTF`, added `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\usepackage{expl3}` some of my lua code failed(saying some functions did not exist). Going to try werners method

Comment: @AbstractDissonance Did you use `\tl_if_empty:NTF` or `\tl_if_empty:nTF` - the two are distinct. I really would appreciate an example so I can check there is not an issue in `epxl3`: could you e-mail me what you saw (joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk)?

Comment: @AbstractDissonance You said you added `\ExplSyntaxOn`, did you also include the corresponding `\ExplSyntaxOff` after defining the command?

Comment: @ScottH. Yes, At first I didn't and was getting other errors so I added that. It is possible I messed something else up.

Comment: The code has changed significantly. It is possible I messed something up. The only thing I'm really doing is including lua files into lualatex. The error was about a missing function(my lua entry point) and either it was due to the include file not being included or for some reason it was not being found like normal. It was most likely user error.