# Weird xparse issue involving splitlist

Tags: xparse

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\test{o}{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{No value or     empty!}{-#1-}}
```

works, but when we try to use a split list the NoValueOrEmpty test fails:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\test{ > { \SplitList { , } }o}{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{No value or empty!}{-#1-}}
```

It seems an empty splitlist is not the same as empty?

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}[3]
{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}
    {
    \def\@tempa{#1}
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty#2\else#3\fi
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I think that has to do with the fact each element is wrapped in a brace group `{}`, so just using `\IfNoValueTF #1` (without the braces) should work.

Comment: Seems that both `\IfNoValueTF{#1}` and `\IfNoValueTF #1 ` seem to work just fine for me. And even using `\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF`, so perhaps I did not properly set up the test case. Can you post a complete MWE.

Comment: @PeterGrill try `\IfNoValueTF #1` with `\test{a,b,c}`, it will fail, since `\SplitList` causes `#1` to be `{a}{b}{c}`.

Comment: As I [commented elsewhere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63226), empty arguments and missing (`NoValue`) arguments are not the same. Trying to test as you are suggests that your input syntax is not well-behaved.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but there is also a difference between an empty argument, novalue, and empty list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After `\SplitList`, an initially empty arguments yields `{}`, the token list with one item, which is empty.  So replace the emptyness test with `\tl_if_eq:nnTF {#1} { {} }`.  Namely,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrSplitEmptyTF}{mmm}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      {#2}
      { \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#1} { {} } {#2} {#3} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\test} { > { \SplitList { , } } o }
  {\IfNoValueOrSplitEmptyTF {#1} {No value} {-#1-}}
\begin{document}
\test
\test[]
\test[,]
\test[a,b,{c=d,e,f},g]
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure you should be ignoring the user's will to have an empty argument: typically, no argument and an empty optional argument should behave differently.

Comment: I think his working case `\DeclareDocumentCommand\test{o}{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{No value or empty!}{-#1-}}` now fails with this for `\test[]`.  An empty test in place of `#3` fixes it.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, Another way is simply to do ` \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {No value or empty!}
    {
        \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF #1
        {No value or empty!}        
        {
            xxx#1xxx
        }
    }` Where we first check the value to be empty and if not then we check the list to be empty.

Comment: @ScottH. That's why I included the word `Split` in the command name for my test: presumably, AbstractDissonance knows if he has split the argument or not.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance No, try with an argument such as `a,b,c`: `\SplitList` produces `{a}{b}{c}`, and `\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF` would take `a`, `b`, and `c` as its argument.  Try it.  If you really want, use `\tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}` in place of `#3` in the code.

Comment: Yes, your right.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought the `Split` indicated inclusion rather than restriction and so thought it was a minor oversight.